# How to output a centrally rotated image in a PDF, but the result always rotates from its top left corner?

Tags: c++, pdf, transform

There is a C++ project at hand that requires implementing the output of a centrally rotated image to a PDF. Through testing, it has been determined that the coordinate system's origin is located at the top left corner.

The following transformation matrix:

```
MatrixTransform aTrans;
aTrans.translate(-halfwidth, -halfheight);
aTrans.rotate(0.7853981634);
aTrans.translate(it->m_dLeft+halfwidth, it->m_dTop+halfheight);
DrawImage(sImageName, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
```

The implementation of MatrixTransform (not the focus):

```
class MatrixTransform {
public:
    MatrixTransform(): m_matrix({0}){
        m_matrix[0][0] = 1.0f;
        m_matrix[1][1] = 1.0f;
        m_matrix[2][2] = 1.0f;
    }

    void translate(float tx, float ty) {
        m_matrix[0][2] += tx;
        m_matrix[1][2] += ty;
    }

    void rotate(float angle) {
        // Construct a rotation matrix
        float cosAngle = std::cos(angle);
        float sinAngle = std::sin(angle);
        float rotationMatrix[3][3] = {
            {cosAngle, -sinAngle, 0.0f},
            {sinAngle, cosAngle, 0.0f},
            {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}
        };

        multiplyMatrix(rotationMatrix);
    }

public:
    float m_matrix[3][3];

    void multiplyMatrix(float matrix[3][3]) {
        float resultMatrix[3][3] = {0};

        for (int row = 0; row < 3; ++row) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; ++col) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
                    resultMatrix[row][col] += m_matrix[row][i] * matrix[i][col];
                }
            }
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < 3; ++row) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; ++col) {
                m_matrix[row][col] = resultMatrix[row][col];
            }
        }
    }
};
```

There is a DrawImage(const char* sImageName, MatrixTransform aTrans, double dX, double dY, double dW, double dH) function for drawing. Its implementation:

```
m_pPage->Save();
//What does this transformation mean, and why is the transformation only related to the height of the page
m_pPage->SetTransform(
    aTrans.m_matrix[0][0],
    -aTrans.m_matrix[0][1],
    -aTrans.m_matrix[1][0], 
    aTrans.m_matrix[1][1],
    aTrans.m_matrix[0][2] + aTrans.m_matrix[1][0] * PageHeight,
    PageHeight - PageHeight * aTrans.m_matrix[1][1] - aTrans.m_matrix[1][2]);

m_pPage->Draw(sImageName, dX, m_dPageHeight - dY - dH, dW, dH);
m_pPage->Restore();
```

Implementation of the related function：

```
void Page::SetTransform(double dM11, double dM12, double dM21, double dM22, double dX, double dY)
{
    Matrix oInverse = m_pState->m_Matrix.Inverse();

    //What does this transformation mean, and why should the inverse matrix be used for the transformation
    Matrix oResult;
    oResult.m11 = dM11 * oInverse.m11 + dM12 * oInverse.m21;
    oResult.m12 = dM11 * oInverse.m12 + dM12 * oInverse.m22;
    oResult.m21 = dM21 * oInverse.m11 + dM22 * oInverse.m21;
    oResult.m22 = dM21 * oInverse.m12 + dM22 * oInverse.m22;
    oResult.x   =   dX * oInverse.m11 +   dY * oInverse.m21 + oInverse.x;
    oResult.y   =   dX * oInverse.m12 +   dY * oInverse.m22 + oInverse.y;

    Concat(oResult.m11, oResult.m12, oResult.m21, oResult.m22, oResult.x, oResult.y);
}

void Page::Draw(const char* sImageName, double dX, double dY, double dWidth, double dHeight)
{
    Save();
    Concat(dWidth, 0, 0, dHeight, dX, dY);
    m_pStream->WriteEscapeName(sImageName);
    m_pStream->WriteStr(" Do\012");
    Restore();
}

Matrix Matrix::Inverse()
{
    Matrix oInverse;

    double dDet = m11 * m22 - m12 * m21;
    if (dDet < 0.0001 && dDet > 0.0001)
        return oInverse;

    oInverse.m11 =  m22 / dDet;
    oInverse.m12 = -m12 / dDet;
    oInverse.m21 = -m21 / dDet;
    oInverse.m22 =  m11 / dDet;
    oInverse.x   =  y * m21 / dDet - x * m22 / dDet;
    oInverse.y   =  x * m12 / dDet - y * m11 / dDet;

    return oInverse;
}

void Page::Concat(double dM11, double dM12, double dM21, double dM22, double dX, double dY)
{
    m_pStream->WriteReal(dM11);
    m_pStream->WriteChar(' ');
    m_pStream->WriteReal(dM12);
    m_pStream->WriteChar(' ');
    m_pStream->WriteReal(dM21);
    m_pStream->WriteChar(' ');
    m_pStream->WriteReal(dM22);
    m_pStream->WriteChar(' ');
    m_pStream->WriteReal(dX);
    m_pStream->WriteChar(' ');
    m_pStream->WriteReal(dY);
    m_pStream->WriteStr(" cm\012");

    Matrix oM = m_pState->m_oMatrix;

    m_pState->m_oMatrix.m11 = dM11 * oM.m11 + dM12 * oM.m21;
    m_pState->m_oMatrix.m12 = dM11 * oM.m12 + dM12 * oM.m22;
    m_pState->m_oMatrix.m21 = dM21 * oM.m11 + dM22 * oM.m21;
    m_pState->m_oMatrix.m22 = dM21 * oM.m12 + dM22 * oM.m22;
    m_pState->m_oMatrix.x   =   dX * oM.m11 + dY * oM.m21 + oM.x;
    m_pState->m_oMatrix.y   =   dX * oM.m12 + dY * oM.m22 + oM.y;
}
    
void Page::Save()
{
    State* pState = new State(m_pState);
    if (!pState)
        return;
    m_pState = pState;
}
void Page::Restore()
{
    if (!m_pState->m_pPrev)
        return;

    State* pPrev = m_pState->m_pPrev;
    delete m_pState;
    m_pState = pPrev;
}

State::State(State* pCurrent)
{
    if (pCurrent)
    {
        m_oMatrix        = pCurrent->m_oMatrix;
        m_pPrev          = pCurrent;
    }
    else
    {
        m_pPrev          = NULL;
    }
}
```

The entire process should be explained clearly. I'm not sure how to set the transformation for this DrawImage function, and I can't seem to achieve the desired effect of center rotation. This issue is quite frustrating, and it seems that I lack the relevant theoretical knowledge. If there is any key information missing, please let me know, and thank you.

Comment: `State* pState = new State(m_pState); if (!pState) return;` -- FYI -- The `!pState` can never happen.  It's either going to have a valid pointer, or a `std::bad_alloc` exception will be thrown.  Thus the compiler may do some optimization tricks behind your back.

Comment: The `DrawImage` and why it only pays attention to the page height: it looks like it's doing a "fit image to page", based on page height.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes.You are right.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Can you analyze where the problem lies? Or can you recommend an expert who can help me understand this issue?